# How to have a templated function require its argument be passed by rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-rvalue-reference

Because of the confusing syntax of forwarding references and rvalue references, it's not clear to me how I would write a function that takes some type, `T`, by rvalue reference. That is, while

```
template <typename T> void foo(T x);
```

takes `x` by value and

```
template <typename T> void foo(T& x);
```

by reference, and

```
template <typename T> void foo(T* x);
```

by pointer, when we say

```
template <typename T> void foo(T&& x);
```

suddenly it's taking `x` by forwarding reference not by rvalue reference. What's the Right Way to say `foo` takes `x` by forwarding reference? Like this?

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& x) {
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>, "x must be an rvalue reference.");
```

Comment: The above is a good start, but this template will still participate in overload resolution which is usually undesirable. I'm too lazy to confirm this this, but you probably want an extra `typename=std::enable_if_t<std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>>` template parameter, instead. Or, even better, declare this whole thing as the return value, in place of an explicit `void`, if the extra template parameter looks too ugly in error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
template<class T>
void f(T &&)
requires(!std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>);
```

Comment: Do you mean `requires(!std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>)`? (Related to this question, I'm a little fuzzy on what `T` is in the case that the argument is `T&&`...)

Comment: Updated. It should be lvalue as rvalue references are harmless for matching against `T`.

Comment: @bpill is there any way it would wind up being a value rather than a reference type? Wouldn’t it be more direct to require it to be an rvalue reference?

Comment: See, if you call it with a rvalue (`f(T{});`) T is deduced to be a non-reference. You can also manually instantiate it with T being a rvalue reference: `f<U &&>(U{});`; only lvalues are forbidden by the requirement.